# select all values in 1 row from table where same value in column

Tags: mysqli

I have rows in my database example

```
col1     col2      col3
test1   value1      5
test1   value2      10
test1   value3      12
test2   value1      2
test2   value2      8
test2   value3      10
test3   value1      8
test3   value2      7
test3   value3      11
```

i want select all values in 1 row from my table where same value in column

```
col1 value1 value2 value3
test1   5      10     12
test2   2      8     10
test3   8      7     11
```

Sorry If my english is bad

After Edited :
my query :

```
SELECT  T.`col1`,

        CASE 
            WHEN T.`col2`='value1'  
            THEN T.`col3` 
        END
     AS 'value1',

        CASE 
            WHEN T.`col2`='value2' 
            THEN T.`col3` 
        END
     AS 'value2',        
     CASE 
            WHEN T.`col2`='value3' 
            THEN T.`col3` 
        END
     AS 'value3',

FROM    table T
GROUP BY T.`col1`;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No

Comment: I want show values and this url about 1 or 0

Comment: Please Show After  Edit @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is close to being correct, except that you forgot to take aggregates of your `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN col2 = 'value1' THEN col3 END) AS value1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN col2 = 'value2' THEN col3 END) AS value2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN col2 = 'value3' THEN col3 END) AS value3
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    col1;
```

Comment: my question not about sum

Comment: col1
value1
value2
value3
test1
5
NULL
NULL
test2
2
NULL
NULL
test3
8
NULL
NULL

Comment: value2 and value3 Null !!

Comment: Both queries from Tim Biegeleisen work: [with sum](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8866/3/0) or [with max](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8866/4/0) @PHPProgrammer

Comment: Very Good  Thanks @tim

Comment: Tim is there a way to get the same result without hardcoding `AS value1` and so on? Like how to get the result dynamically if there is a "value4" at some point?

Comment: @caramba If you're asking for dynamic SQL, then I don't know it.